# Android arrays of unknown number of items

Tags: android, arrays, numbers, size, items

If I dont know how many items array will have, can I do

```
long[] longarray = new long[99];
```

and then

```
longarray[0] = 11;
longarray[1] = 22;
longarray[2] = 33;
```

? so, will be created from about 5 to 60 items, I estimate.

Does the declaration of 99 items take a lot of memory ?

**MY ANSWER:**

```
long[] longarray = new long[1];
long[] temparray;
int cnt = -1;
int cntp;
...
public void myAdd(long value) {
    cnt++;
    cntp = cnt + 1;
    if (cnt == 0) { longarray[0] = value } //the first time
    else {
    temparray = new long[cnt];
    System.arraycopy(longarray, 0, temparray, 0, cnt);
    longarray = new long[cntp];
    System.arraycopy(temparray, 0, longarray, 0, cnt);
    longarray[cnt] = value;
    }
}
```

That is basicly what listarray add() does.

Comment: But normally you would use arrays when the amount of space you need is known right? This is pretty dangerous, and I would suggest just using a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **long** takes up 8 byte in memory, so an array of 99 long takes (99 * 8) bytes + a few bytes for overhead.
Saying if it is a lot or not really depend on your use case, but for most system it is not much.

But this is really not a good practice, and if you don't have a good reason not to, you really should use a List. They handle dynamic allocation like champs.

And if you have a reason to not use a List, please tell us.

Comment: So just the initialization request the memory ?

Comment: I dont like lists because I need performance and its not "classic/basic" code, like c++...

Answer (score 0):

Use a List. Most common built-in lists in Java are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`:

```
List<Long> longlist = new ArrayList<Long>;
longlist.add(11);
longlist.add(22);
longlist.add(33);
```

etc. Retrieve values with `longlist.get(i)` where `i` is your index.